# Compilation Errors in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm been trying for the last couple of hours to solve an error that I can't get rid of. Here it is the gist: https://gist.github.com/pluralism/11294490

I'm out of ideas because everything looks correct for me. The compilation error I'm getting is the following:

> `1>MenuCAL.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl printSquareArray(int * *,unsigned int)" (?printSquareArray@@YAXPAPAHI@Z) already defined in calproject.obj
>   1>C:\Users\Andre Pinheiro\Desktop\calproject\Debug\calproject.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

If you need other files please feel free to ask. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define `printSquareArray` in a header, mark it `inline` to allow a definition in every translation unit that includes the header.

Alternatively, move the definition into a source file, so it's only defined once.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I'll accept your answer as soon as possible